# Regular Expression / Substring function in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I have a list of last names that can have variations like this-->DOE, JR., DO.  What I need is a Postgres pattern matching or substring function that will split the DO from the last name and put that a separate column.  However, if the pattern is like this DOE, JR. I don't want those split off names suffixes, only professional titles which I need to list like MD, DDS, DMD, or DO.  Someone I work with suggested I use something like this -->Substring(last_name, ‘[MD, DDS, DMD, DO,etc.]$’) but that is not working.

```
select substring('.do' FROM last_name) AS license from table
```

Comment: He might have suggested this `(MD|DDS|DMD|DO|etc.)$` . Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the license (less any trailing whitespace):

```
select regexp_matches(last_name, '(MD|DDS|DMD|DO|etc)\s*$') AS license from table;
```